# Должны ли в google console лежать оба ключа: debug и release?

Tags: android

Должны ли в google console для карты console.developers.google.com лежать оба ключа: debug и release?

---

Оригинальный вопрос:

*Оба ключа должно желать в google console релиз и дебаг для карты console.developers.google.com*

Comment: Не смог понять, о чём вообще речь =/

Comment: в андроиде для отображения карт должны получить Ключь, дебаг ключ  отображается, как ставляю релиз ключ карта белая

Comment: попытался переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: в одном проекте есть два ключа один для debug Другой для релиза, оба они должно лежать в консоле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В консоли должны быть зарегистрированы те сертификаты, которыми вы подпишете приложение и хотите видеть работающую карту.
`Release` там обязательно должен быть, `Debug` на Ваше усмотрение, если хотите видеть карту в процессе разработки и отладки.